# Rewriterules 301 with round brackets into the URL it's not working

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with a Rewriterule that it's not working.
It's something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/es/rootpage/specific-page-(something)(.*).html$ https://website.com/es/another-root-page/specific-something$1 [NC,L,R=301,ENV=REDIRECTCACHE:1]
```

When I try to visit the first link it redirects me on:
`https://website.com/es/another-root-page/specific-page-(something)` instead of `https://website.com/es/another-root-page/specific-something`.

What I've tried to do is put an escape character (the backslash) this way `\(something\)(.*).html` but it's not worked at all.
I've tried to use the encoded ASCII character for the rounded brackets and still nothing.

Do you have any advice?

Comment: Where in your config are you using this rule?

Comment: I'm sorry @MrWhite What do you mean? 
I'm pretty new on this topic!

Comment: Server config, virtual host, `<Directory>` section, `.htaccess`? And do you have any other rules?

Comment: Virtual host! Yes, I have plenty more of them, list 500 redirect rules in the same file!

Comment: "When I try to visit the first link it redirects me" - What "first link"? What is the actual URL you are requesting?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite thanksfully I've resolved easily this issue after a "hard" restart of the machine (as I've explained into the solution!). Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the "\" character works well as a escape character for the vhost RewriteRule.

The problem was that I've used this command to restart the dispatcher machine so it was extremely slow:

```
apachectl -k graceful
```

So just do a "hard" restart or wait enough time.

I hope that this info will help someone else with similar issues!